# How can one locally install an extension to an existing system python module?

Tags: python, module

I'm having trouble installing an extension to an existing Python module on a remote system I have no root access on, such as installing [mpl_toolkits.basemap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.6/).  The system *does* have `mpl_toolkits` but *not* `mpl_toolkits.basemap`, and I can't install `basemap` to the system-wide site-packages directory (no root access).

If I install `mpl_toolkits.basemap` to `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/mpl_toolkits` then

```py
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

will either be unable to find `basemap` because `sys.path` first lead it to the system-wide `mpl_toolkits` package, or if `sys.path` first leads to my local install then I can't use the full, system-wide `mpl_toolkits`.

My solution is to locally install `basemap` as `mpl_toolkits_ext.basemap` and modify any code to import `basemap` from `mpl_toolkits_ext` instead of the expected `mpl_toolkits`.

This works, but is inelegant and error-prone.  Is there a "proper" way to install extensions to Python modules?  I'd like Python to first search the system's `mpl_toolkits` and then if it finds nothing to check my local installation of `mpl_toolkits` (`$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/mpl_toolkits`) before giving up.

Comment: IMHO best solution is to use virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate your sys.path to change the search order like you want it to have? But the naming might indeed be a problem. But if you can install mpl_toolkits.basemap, why not also install mpl_toolkits locally?

Comment: I could indeed install the full mpl_toolkits locally but (1) this doesn't feel much more elegant than changing my local install's name to mpl_toolkits_ext and (2) the remote system is pretty complicated and often updated / changed and I'd rather not maintain a large package like mpl_toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

With a change to the basemap package (submitted here https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/pull/154) I could import the out-of-system-wide mpl_toolkits.basemap in a way like this:

(this was quickly made, some of the stuff is probably not necessary)

mybasemap.py in the basemap mpl_toolkits dir (might need to change those):

```
from mpl_toolkits import *
import mpl_toolkits

import sys
sys.path.insert (0, './mpl_toolkits/')
sys.path.insert (1, './')

from basemap import Basemap
```

then do:

```
from mybasemap import Basemap
```

in the final script (after adding the path to mybasemap.py).